# How to add client side validation to ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I implemented [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) to my project but I didn't find any info how to add client side validation to it. By default it pass all requests to backend.

In **sessionAuthenticationFailed** function I can handle all errors from backend but how I can add client-side validation?

My code is default in example but still mb I do something wrong.

LoginController.coffee

```
App.LoginController = Em.Controller.extend(SimpleAuth.LoginControllerMixin,
  authenticator: "simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant"
)
```

LoginRoute.coffee

```
App.LoginRoute = Em.Route.extend

  actions:
    sessionAuthenticationFailed: (response) ->
      console.log 'sessionAuthenticationFailed', response
```

login.emblem

```
.b-content

  .b-content__body
    form.b-form submit='authenticate'

      Ember.TextField id='identification' valueBinding='identification' class='b-form__input'

      Ember.TextField id='password' type='password' valueBinding='password' class='b-form__input'

      button.b-form__submit.b-button.b-button--primary.ts-submit type='submit'
        | Enter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply override the `App.LoginController`'s `authenticate` action and only call `super` if your client side validations pass.